# how to check that textbox id is null or not in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am facing the length error in my nodejs mongodb database connection programm

I have tried with mongodb compass

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('views',__dirname);

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/productDB";

app.post('/submitData',urlEncodedParser,function(req,res){
    var id = req.body.id;
    var productCode = req.body.txtCode;
    var productName = req.body.txtName;
    var price = req.body.txtPrice;
    var taxable = req.body.radioTax;

    console.log("length:%d",id.length);

    if(id.length > 0)
    {
        MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
            if(err)
                throw err;
             var qry = {productCode:productCode};
             var data = {$set:{productName:productName,price:price,taxable:taxable}};
             db.collection("tblProduct").updateOne(qry,data,function(err,res){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                console.log("Updated");
                db.close();
             });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            db.collection('tblProduct').insertOne({
                productCode:productCode,
                productName:productName,
                price:price,
                taxable:taxable
            });
            console.log("Inserted");
        });
    }
    res.redirect("/showProduct");
});
```

I am expecting the result as length of id. I want solution of length error as well as I want to check that my textbox is null or not. If it is null then it  will insert new record and if it is not null it will update existing one.

Comment: Have you tried `if(id != null)`? or `if(!id)`?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. what happens when you use the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(typeof id != 'undefined')
    {
        MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
            if(err)
                throw err;
             var qry = {productCode:productCode};
             var data = {$set:{productName:productName,price:price,taxable:taxable}};
             db.collection("tblProduct").updateOne(qry,data,function(err,res){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                console.log("Updated");
                db.close();
             });
        });
    }
```